# Merge git branch without moving branch pointer

Tags: git

I'm looking for a solution to apply a feature branch to the development branch in git without actually moving the branch pointer. Essentially, I'd like to create a single commit off of the feature branch and make sure it's pointing at the originating branch somehow (mention in the log might be enough).

I know that stacked git should offer something like that, although that would introduce new commands to the standard workflow which I'd rather avoid.

What I'm trying to achieve is some sort of feature management which allows us to apply / remove whole features, while keeping the visibility of the patch branch itself. If I do merge the branch, most commands trying to diff the change will not do what I want because the branch is already merged into develop.

I cannot really follow the upstream - sometimes there are concurrent changes which are easier to correct by getting new tag and reapplying only needed features, rather than resolving conflicts and reverting redundant features - so this way of work is not possible. On the other hand I do want to see the change, so that I can either rework it to match new version, or submit upstream at a later time.

Comment: So you want to squash the whole feature branch to one single patch and be able to freely apply/revert it within develop branch, am I right?

Comment: Well - I want a single commit which means "this was the XYZ branch at some point, ending with commit <hash>" but I don't want the branch to end at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To what I understand, you may use git rebase -i to achieve your goal.
Below is the scenario you want to achieve...

```
A--B--C(develop)
\
 \D--E--F(feature)
```

you can combine D-E-F as a single commit named as G
the final outcome will be

```
   A--B--C--G(develop)
    \
     \D--E--F(feature)
```

G is a single commit that have all the things in D-E-F, and you can easily take it off from the develop branch.

---

So in order to process this surgery, you can do....

`git checkout feature_branch`

make a temp branch...

`git checkout -b temp`

`git rebase -i develop_branch`

and interactive editor will be prompted out...
mark commit D and E as squash, retain the last line(commit) as your last single commit
save and quit

then a commit G will rebase on to your developement branch.

```
   A--B--C(develop)--G(temp)
    \
     \D--E--F(feature)
```

Reset your development onto commit G and delete temp branch if you want.

```
git checkout develop_branch
git reset --hard <shaSum of commit G>
git -D temp
```

That's it!

Comment: @viraptor: which part of it not too obvious?

Comment: I expected commands like "squash this onto that" or "duplicate list branch onto" to be available already. New branch, manual edit of rebase list (why interactive), reset (what? why?) feel like writing assembler when you need bash script. But that's my issue with git in general, not your solution ;)

Comment: @viraptor: it would be nice if other can post a single command. Btw, that's what I did in my daily job. Creating a new branch is useful for rebasing, (you can still keep the feature branch), interactive rebase is necessary if you want to squash into single commit, reset is to reset your development to the same point as the temp branch. :)

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there is an easier method. The `git merge` command has an option `--squash`, which just accumulates all the changes from the branch to be merged, and adds them to the staging area.

So, you can do what you want with the following commands (when you are on master, and want to merge feature branch feature-foobar):

```
$ git merge --squash feature-foobar
$ git commit -m "Implemented feature: foobar"
```